# Stop EE from obfuscating email address in template

Tags: templates, email, encode

How do I get EE to actually print out the email {apply_email} instead of making a javascript obfuscated email address in the templates? Is there an option I can put on the tag to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Channel preference setting to [automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#automatically-turn-urls-and-email-addresses-into-links) than when enabled does some auto-typography to create links. Disabled, it will leave your naked email addresses and URLs in content fields alone.